Using proxychains with cloudflared tunnel to expose a tcp application without cloudflare WARP on client's end
I am in a unique situation where I am getting my internet exclusively through cellular/LTE. It just so happens that because of this, port forwarding is not an option. I would need to work around the NAT if I ever want to host anything. I am hoping that there is a way to do so without the use of a service like tailscale or doing the VPS + NGINX method, because both methods would undoubtedly add latency or cost money.
I recently attempted to mess with cloudflare's tunnels, which seem promising, although there is one dealbreaker for me. TCP forwarding without an app required on the client's end is a paid feature.
So after some digging I discovered proxychains, which apparently allows packets from tcp applications to be sent across http proxies.
I was wondering if it would somehow be possible network things in a way that resembles the following:
application (tcp) -> proxychains -> cloudflared tunnel (http) -> client (tcp)
Again, the reasons I want to do it in this manner are:

I do not want to pay any more money than absolutely necessary for my hobbyist server
I do not want to manage or pay for a VPS exclusively to expose ports
I do not want to rely on services like tailscale or playit, as their free plans (understandably) add a lot of latency
I already rent domain names from cloudflare, and I trust them (slightly) more than the other options.

It is important that the end client should not need to install an additional application in order to access the service.
Please let me know if any of my assumptions or ideas are plain wrong, as I am completely new to anything having to do with proxies or things beyond the bare minimum of http, and feel free to suggest any solutions I may be missing. Thank you in advance.
(before someone asks, yes one use of this will be a game server. But that is far from the only intended use case!!)

Software and tool recommendations are off-topic. But what you want sounds a lot like ngrok and similar provide and there are also free options.
